# Reading XML files using JSTL

Tags: xml, jsp, jstl

i have an xml file in below format and I need to read 
 ref=1111111/0000000 and
 ref="2222222/0000000
using jstl.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
    <TestDocument xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" >
      <Data>
        <ARUDD>
          <Header reportType="REFT1019" ></Header>
          <AddresseeInformation name="c company"></AddresseeInformation>
          <ServiceLicenseInformation userName="Muhammad" userNumber="785421"></ServiceLicenseInformation>
          <Advice>
            <OriginatingAccountRecords>
              <OriginatingAccountRecord>
                <OriginatingAccount name="My Account" ></OriginatingAccount>
                <ReturnedDebitItem ref="0000000" >
                </PayerAccount>
                </ReturnedDebitItem>
                <Totals numberOf="1" valueOf="500.00" currency="GBP"></Totals>
              </OriginatingAccountRecord>
              <OriginatingAccountRecord>
                <OriginatingAccount name="Originating account " number="000000" sortCode="00-00-00"></OriginatingAccount>
                <ReturnedDebitItem ref="xxxxxxx/0000000   " transCode="17" >
                **<PayerAccount number="aaaaaaa" **ref="1111111/0000000"**>**
                </PayerAccount></ReturnedDebitItem>
                <ReturnedDebitItem ref="yyyyyyy/0000000   " transCode="01" >
                **<PayerAccount number="bbbbbbb" **ref="2222222/0000000"** >**
                </PayerAccount></ReturnedDebitItem>
                <Totals numberOf="111" valueOf="2111" currency="GBP"></Totals>
              </OriginatingAccountRecord>
            </OriginatingAccountRecords>
          </Advice>
        </ARUDD>
      </Data>
      </BACSDocument>
```

the code I am using to read this (without any luck) is

```
  <c:import var="url" url="data.xml"/>
            <x:parse   xml="${url}"   var="doc" />  
            <x:forEach   var="n"  select="$doc/TestDocument/Data/ARUDD/Advice/OriginatingAccountRecords/OriginatingAccountRecord/OriginatingAccount/ReturnedDebitItem"> 
          <option> <x:out select="$n/ref" />  </option>

           </x:forEach>
```

I have another file in the same location and I can read it without any problem.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="yes"?>
    <ISO_3166-1_List_en xml:lang="en">
       <ISO_3166-1_Entry>
          <ISO_3166-1_Country_name>AFGHANISTAN</ISO_3166-1_Country_name>
          <ISO_3166-1_Alpha-2_Code_element>AF</ISO_3166-1_Alpha-2_Code_element>
       </ISO_3166-1_Entry>
       <ISO_3166-1_Entry>
          <ISO_3166-1_Country_name>ÅLAND ISLANDS</ISO_3166-1_Country_name>
          <ISO_3166-1_Alpha-2_Code_element>AX</ISO_3166-1_Alpha-2_Code_element>
       </ISO_3166-1_Entry>
     </ISO_3166-1_List_en>


 <c:import var="url" url="countries.xml"/>
  <x:parse   xml="${url}"   var="doc" />  

   <x:forEach   var="n"  select="$doc/ISO_3166-1_List_en/ISO_3166-1_Entryy"> 
  <!--  select="$output/ISO_3166-1_List_en/ISO_3166-1_Entry[2]/ISO_3166-1_Country_name" -->

   <option> <x:out select="$n/ISO_3166-1_Country_name" />  </option>

 </x:forEach>
```

please can you help?

thanks

Comment: Looks like this is similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7027091/parsing-xml-file-using-java-jstl-library-xout-does-not-display-node-specific-d

The problem can be with namespace in xml. Try a document without a namespace and see if this works.

Comment: See http://pro-programmers.blogspot.com/2008/04/jstl-xparse-not-working-for-elements.html

Comment: I have changed the namespace but still no luck.

Comment: Is that last line a typo ? </BACSDocument> should be </TestDocument>

Comment: yes it is. in the file, the start and end tags are same.

Answer (score 0):

Use a different variable and a minimal path to see what the file contents are:

```
<x:set var="foo" select="$doc" /> 
<x:out select="$foo" />
```