# Use XML-Content in <jsp:setProperty

Tags: jsp, debugging, jstl, javabeans, jsp-tags

im trying to set some Content in my JavaBean. I'm doing the following:

```
    <x:set var="asdf123" select="$record/uuid"/>
    <c:out value="${asdf123}"/> <---- this displays []
    <x:out select="$record/uuid" /> <---- this displays the content from my XML 
    <x:out select="$asdf123" /> <---- this displays the content from my XML
    <jsp:useBean id="matchBean" class="my.project.beans.MatchBean" />
    <jsp:setProperty name="matchBean" property="uuid" value="${asdf123}"/> <--- this isn't working
```

I already put the content in a hidden input field in my form. This works just with a

```
<input type="radio" name="uuid" value="<x:out select="$record/uuid" />" checked="checked" />
```

this one works. I tried similar things for my Bean, but without any result so far.

Thank you

Markus

Answer (score 0):

> This one did the trick:

```
<x:set var="asdf123" select="string($record/uuid/text())"/>
```

**References**

- [jstl xml variables for select attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23251179/1113772)
- [Reading XML files using JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9621528/1113772)
- [java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.xpath.VariableStack when use jstl xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19325741/1113772)