# jstl xml variables for select attribute

Tags: xml, jsp, jstl

I'm using jstl xml to get specified values from an XML

Here I'm using a "userRoleSelector" as a variable to select the node. The variable is set as,

```
<c:set var="userRoleSelector" value="role-id='test'" scope='session'/>
```

The tag where I use the variable is as follows,

```
<x:if select="$parsedRoleXML//roles/role[$userRoleSelector]/features/feature[text()='viewEvents']">
        //html code
</x:if>
```

The node is not selected according to the role-id provided. it works if I use only the right hand side as a variable.

What is the issue here?

Answer (score 2):

There are a few problems here:

- The XPath predicate syntax `[$userRoleSelector]` is not doing a comparison
- The XPath predicate syntax is searching for an index, not an attribute value
- `userRoleSelector` is not an XPath variable
- `c:set` variables are not in the XML scope, unlike `x:parse` variables
- `userRoleSelector` is a JSP variable

To test the role-id properly, try this instead:

```
[@role-id='test']
```

To test the JSP variable, try this instead:

```
[@role-id=$sessionScope:userRoleSelector]
```

**References**

- [XPath: Variable Reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#NT-VariableReference)
- [JSP - XML Data](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_xml_data.htm)
- [JSR-52: jstl-1_0-fr-spec.pdf](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/7764-jstl-1.0-fr-spec-oth-JSpec/)